# How to convert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which I want to convert into a dictionary.

```
q2 = [{'ComplainDepartment':'Academic','count':1}, 
      {'ComplainDepartment':'Hostel','count':2}]
```

Change it to:

```
data = {'Academic':1,'Hostel':2}
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (dict comprehension):

```
{q.get('ComplainDepartment'): q.get('count') for q in q2}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a generator comprehension to extract the `values` from each dictionary and build a new `dictionary` from the result:

```
dict(d.values() for d in q2)
# {'Academic': 1, 'Hostel': 2}
```

---

Or using [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html):

```
dict(map(dict.values, q2))
# # {'Academic': 1, 'Hostel': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}
for dictionary in q2:
    data[dictionary["ComplainDepartment"]] = dictionary["count"]
```